# Test file initialization based off template using ChefSpec

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chefspec

I've got the following template file creation in my cookbook:

```
template "my_file" do
  path "my_path"
  source "my_file.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0644"
  variables(@template_variables)
  notifies :restart, resources(service: "my_service")
end
```

and the following assertions in my ChefSpec tests:

```
  chef_run.should create_file "my_file"
  chef_run.file("my_file").should be_owned_by('root', 'root')
```

Which results in the following failure:

```
  No file resource named 'my_file' with action :create found.
```

This is due to the fact that I am not using a`file` resource but a `template` resource. Question: How can I test for file creation off a template resource using ChefSpec?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem? The syntax for ChefSpec matchers has changed since this question was posted. Does the given answer solve your problem?

Comment: o I'm sorry I completely forgot about this question. Gonna go recheck whats up and see

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to solve your problem.

First, you can use the `create_template` matcher. This will match only "template" resources in the run context:

```
expect(chef_run).to create_template('my_file')
```

This matcher is also chainable, so you can assert attributes:

```
expect(chef_run).to create_template('my_file')
  .with_path('my_path')
  .with_owner('root')
```

However, this matcher won't *actually* render the template. So you can't check if you've setup file-specificity correctly.

There's also a top-level matcher for any kind of "file" (`file`, `cookbook_file`, and `template`) that actually renders the contents in memory:

```
expect(chef_run).to render_file('my_file').with_content(/^match me$/)
```

You can find more information about [`render_file` in the README](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec#render_file).

Comment: The quality of my chefspec just increased by a factor of 3. Is it possible to use multiple with_content set? `should render_file('somefile').with_content(/content1/).with_content(/content2/)`

only matches the 2nd regex, never parses the first.

Comment: No, with_content is not an additive matcher.

Comment: so the approach for testing multiple matches of content would be to assign the `.to render_file('myfile')` to a variable and then run with_content against that.

Answer (score 5):

According to the docs (https://github.com/acrmp/chefspec) you should be able to use:

```
expect(chef_run).to create_file 'my_file'
```

I think something changed very recently (possibly the version of chefspec on rubygems), however, because tests I had passing earlier today (using the same syntax you are using) are now suddenly failing.